# React.js Template Not Rendering Properly

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on the React.js tutorial here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I have everything working as expected, but for some reason, when I apply additional HTML to my form with classes, the styling doesn't apply. I have checked out a bit of additional documentation, but can't find a reason why the additional HTML won't render.

The form elements will render, but nothing with the 'large-XX columns' classes will render.

Any thoughts?

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
 handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var creator = this.refs.creator.value.trim();
    var mr = this.refs.mr.value.trim();
    var message = this.refs.message.value.trim();
    var csrfmiddlewaretoken = this.refs.csrfmiddlewaretoken.value.trim();
    if (!creator || !mr || !message || !csrfmiddlewaretoken ) {
        return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({creator:creator, mr:mr, message:message, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfmiddlewaretoken})
    this.refs.creator.value = '';
    this.refs.mr.value = '';
    this.refs.message.value = '';
    return;
},

render: function() {
return (
  <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="hidden" ref="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
            <input type="hidden" ref="creator" value="{{ globalEmployee.id }}" />
            <input type="hidden" ref="mr" value="{{ mr.id }}" />
            <input type="text" ref="message" placeholder="Add a comment..." />
        </div>
        <div class="large-12 columns">
        </div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <input type="submit" value="Post" class="button tiny expand" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `class` use `className` as you did in the `form` element.

From [HTML Tags vs. React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components):

> Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as class and for are
>   discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components
>   expect DOM property names like className and htmlFor, respectively.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the help.